# The errror message "We don't have as many of some products as you want" is showing while adding the product to cart

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, cart, addtocart

I am getting the error message "We don't have as many of some products as you want" while adding the product to cart.

Help me to resolve this.

Comment: please check products quantity are available or not for that particular product from magento admin backend.

Comment: I checked. It is available. I set it as 1000. But still don't know why it is showing like that

Comment: We set it as no manage stock for that product because it is a sample product for main product.

Comment: may you need to reindex command

Comment: reindex also done.

Comment: Check/debug in this file: `/magento/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart.php` function`addProductsByIds` if helpful.

Comment: I am checking that. But can you tell me in what cases such type of error message will show?

Comment: Please check your log error